# Probability mass function - the transfer over a network.

Tags: probability

W transfer over a computer network will succeed with probability $\dfrac{a}{d}$ and fail with probability $1-\dfrac{a}{d}$. We try to send a file over a network $n$ times during a second. Let $X_n$ be the waiting time (in seconds) for a successful transfer. Establish a probability mass function and inspect how it behaves when $n \to \infty$.

So the probability, that we waited $n$ seconds for the transfer is $P(\{w \in \Omega, X_{n-1}\lt F(w)\leq X_n\})$. 
Because in order for the transfer to succed at $n$ seconds  it's successful sometime after $n-1$ second, but before $n$ seconds pass, so $P(X_n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{n}\left(\dfrac{a}{n}\right)^k*\left(1-\dfrac{a}{n}\right)^{n^2+k}$.

The reason for $n^2+k$ is because in order to succeed during after $n-1$ seconds we have to fail during $0,...,n-1$ seconds, we have $n$ second to do that with, each with $n$ part, so $n^2$ plus all those times that we fail after $n-1$ second, that's the $k$.

But my solutions seems way to complicated to be correct and to inspect the behaviour of PMF without some complex calculations.